# Time instead of datetime in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to have parameter for time, but when I choose date/time in parameter properties, and set default value to 08:00:00 it gives me 9. November 2011 08:00:00, and I need time for any date.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSRS doesn't have a good built-in parameter for this.

So the options:

- build your own wrapper UI to collect the parameters = lots of work,
  but lots of flexibility.
- Create a dropdown with all likely possible options.
- Use a string or an int (if you can get by with just hours.) and convert this as needed in your report or in your query. (Be careful: the `Time` datatype was only introduced in SQL 2008, so may not work in some environments.)